# Create chunks from an array

Tags: code-golf, array

Your task is to write a program which given an array and a number, you need to split the array into chunks with size is number.

### Rules

Your program will receive an array `A` , as well as  a positive integer `n`. The array should then be split into chunks of length `n`, if the length of the string isn't divisible by `n` any leftover at the end should be considered its own chunk.

- If `n` is greater than length of array `A`, you will need to return array `A`, for example: if `n = 4` and `array A = [1,2,3]`, you should return `[1,2,3]`
- The array can contain any type rather than number.
- You should not change order (or direction) of any item from left to right. For example `if n = 2` and `A= [1,2,3]`. Any result rather than `[[1,2],[3]]` will be invalid.

### Test Cases

```
n   A               Output

2   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
3   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
4   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you the shortest bytes of each language will be the winner.

Comment: What type of numbers can the array contain? Only positive integers as in your example? Real numbers? Complex numbers?

Comment: Hi @Adám, Arnauld, Luis Mendo, could you please take a look again in the **Rules** section, I answered all your questions. Thanks!

Comment: If `n` is greater than the length of `A` we need to return `A`‽ Are you sure you don't mean `[A]`?

Comment: @Adám, sorry if I make my answers not clearly, I just updated it, could you please take a quick look.

Comment: @chaugiang I still think a too large `n` should return `[A]`, e.g `[[1,2,3]]`. What if `n` is exactly the length of `A`?

Comment: @chaugiang Adam is correct imo.  The return value should be consistent.

Comment: @chaugiang Can **n** ever equal **1**?

Comment: In a strongly typed language, it's simply impossible to return `A` rather than `[A] `, which would exclude an awful lot of languages.

Comment: This challenge inspire me to create this one [Deal the cards to the players](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181029/deal-the-cards-to-the-players). Thank you for the idea :)

Comment: Tests are insufficient

Comment: Would it be OK if esolangs without arrays participated? Can we, say, take a list of numbers on input and print `n` numbers per line on output?

Comment: @snail_, yes, it should be okay!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ô
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Jb//024og11jHSMdUx0THXMYgE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/mU1Zpr6TwqG2SgpK9Z@X/w1v@6/yPNtQx0jHWMdEx1TGLBQA).

Builtins ftw. :)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(array)`.

```javascript
n=>g=a=>a+a&&[a.splice(0,n),...g(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq7CsIwFADQvV9xBykJicH6QqzpBzjo4FgKvcQmRMpNaYogpd8edTrLeeEboxn9MK0pPLtkdSJdOY26QoF5XqOKQ@9NxzaSuFRKOYa8STaMjEBDUQLBBU4/hOAwZwAmUAx9p/rgWPs/q5mWM7Qg4Pq431ScRk/O2w@zjDirC7mVO7mXB3lsOOdltqQv)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                  // n = chunk size
  g = a =>            // g = recursive function taking the array a[]
    a + a             // if a[] is empty, stop recursion and return an empty string
    &&                // otherwise, return an array made of:
    [ a.splice(0, n), //   the next chunk
      ...g(a)         //   followed by the result of a recursive call
    ]                 //   (the last call leads to ...'', which adds nothing)
```

Comment: Now that is a neat and clean solution, and I learned about recursive anonymous functions too!

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⊢⊂⍨(⍴⊢)⍴1↑⍨⊣
```

Big thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m) for basically doing basically all the golfing (and for basically all the APL knowledge I have currently >_>).

#### Explanation

```apl
 ⊂⍨           Partitioned enclose (commuted, i.e. left and right switched) - for each ⍵ in left, ⍺ in right, if ⍺ = 0, create a new sub-array, push ⍵ to latest sub-array
⊢             Right argument of entire expression
       ⍴      Reshape - Change size of right into dimensions specified by left
   (⍴ )       Shape of (here, there is only one dimension - length)
     ⊢        Right argument of entire expression
         ↑⍨   Take (commuted) - takes ⍺ elements from left where ⍺ is right. Extra elements (zeroes here) are automatically added
        1     1
           ⊣  Left argument of entire expression
```

#### Execution

Arguments `2`, `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`. Note that APL arrays are of the form `a b c`, with optional surrounding parentheses.

```apl
           ⊣  2
        1     1
         ↑⍨   1↑2 = 1 0
     ⊢        1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   (⍴ )       ⍴1 2 3 4 5 6 7 = 7
       ⍴      7⍴1 0 = 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
⊢             1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 ⊂⍨           1 0 1 0 1 0 1⊂1 2 3 4 5 6 7 = (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v8ahvql/wo941mnogZrCrXqizr4t6Un6FQn6egm6aLYgssS0pSk1Vf9S1ODUvMSknNdjRJwTIAap3jlQvTswpUdf8/6hr0aOupke9KzQe9W4BcjSBlOGjtolAEaDS/2mP2iY86u0DavH0f9TVfGi9MUgOaGGQM5AM8fAM/g@kgYqMFNIUDBWMFIwVTBRMFcy4IKLGWEVNsIqimaBgjt0MuLgJujgA)

Comment: Congratulations on your first APL answer. And nicely explained too! Here, have an APL pie: 

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda A,n:[A,[A[x:x+n]for x in range(0,len(A),n)]][n<len(A)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNboMwEIXX@BQjJITdulITki6ssmDRRc/gWBUBkyBRg8CR6Ompx5AfWhZPeOab5@fpfuy5NclUpYepyb@PZQ4ZN0JmXGZyFOOzUVXbwwi1gT43J01feaMNzRg3TClp3ueTmqwe7AApSALuo3LDYcsh4bDjsOfwptwf40szzmMO8RGlQClRNEqFckI5o9Sxm0tuczfTlYFDtv@RnSvvmasqQvTY6cLq8qu9LCEDuSalz6g4Nv6ay1U@X1glnKfQDntzOk9dLTzwcB1xkXCt9X2tuEa/QsYECdq0ok/@KGvFSND1tbE0/DRATRqVTBxsNITRlZBCvGweuI/luQtGV89HxzuaFfaSNw5E9GDCqGXTLw)

Modifies [Henry T's existing Python 3 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180979/85755) to produce valid output for n >= len(A).
Posting as its own answer due to lack of commenting privileges.

Answer (score 8):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>90</s> <s>84</s> 61 bytes

#### Code:

```
[]*_*[].
L*N*[P|R]:-length(P,N),append(P,T,L),T*N*R;P=L,R=[].
```

The input format might be a bit weird, but it is:

```
A * n * Result.
```

For example, for the input:

```
n = 2
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You would need to use `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] * 2 * Result.`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PzpWK14rOlaPy0fLTys6oCYo1ko3JzUvvSRDI0DHT1MnsaAgNS8FyA7R8dHUCQEqCrIOsPXRCbIFavr/n4sr2lBHwUhHwVhHwURHwVRHwUxHwVxHwSJWQUvBGIiDUotLc0r0uLgA)

#### Ungolfed version:

```
divide([], _, []).
divide(List, N, [Prefix | Result]) :-
    length(Prefix, N), append(Prefix, Remaining, List), divide(Remaining, N, Result) 
  ; Prefix = List, Result = [].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsIwEEX3@Yq7bGBa8C2KfyBFug1BCo11IKalrY@F/x6jjeLs5tzhzG27xjZ12t/Z@4pvXJlEacKRoLTMRER77gdCHuChMyd@4InC9Fc7aIlNKhDGGlcP52TMw60klG1rXPVDhbmU7NjVhLcvHET7X5BTFEsE6xbx3Q5jgzELq9KZ9@JbT00IU8KMMCcsCEvCirDWHxR9mRAv).

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 15 bytes

```php
$f=array_chunk;
```

requires PHP 7. Call with `$f(ARRAY, N)`.

Comment: I don't think you're required to give another name to a builtin, so this just scores 11, doesn't it?

Comment: @Neil I thought that might be a [forbidden loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/55735); but you may be right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
{*.batch($_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WksvKbEkOUNDJV6z9n9xYqVCGoipYainZ6apkJZfpGCkp2di/R8A)

Curried function wrapping the `batch` built-in.

Comment: Did they fix that bug where you had to have a `;` after the Whatever code?

Comment: @JoKing No. You only need a `;` when [passing arguments with `$^a` or `@_`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2487).

Answer (score 5):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 54 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$n l=[l%(i,i+n-1)\\i<-[0,n..length l-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcu9CsIwEADg3ae4oYLipRitTnbTQXDrmGYI6Y8Hl6vYKPjynn77F7kPomnqXtxDCiRK6TE9MzS5u8h7UQhw7Xi5IqSNGLtuWzoZt0UpS@5lzHdgY73XJof/qqGACpzFHe6xwgMevX7jwGGc1Vxvev5ISBTnHw)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 46 chars

```
lambda A,n:[A[:n],*(f(A[n:],n)if A[n:]else[])]
```

-1 thanks to @Collin Phillips.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcs7DsIwEEXRrUzpQa/AhK8lCq/DTGGEDSOFSWTSsHoT0V3p6M7f5TXZ0Ov11sf8vj8yRVhIMQUTbFx1MVkQGGulf5bxU5Kw9Do1UlKjlu1ZnIffcpib2rJeyWOHAXsccMQJZ1xWFihz/wE)

Comment: I was able to get it to [46 characters with recursion](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcFRJ88q2jHaKi9WR0sjTcMxOs8qVidPMzNNAcxMzSlOjY7VjP1fUJSZVwJUEG2oY6RjrGOiY6pjFqtjpKnJhV3GGKeMCU4ZU5wyZpqa/wE)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
i,j=input()
while j:print j[:i];j=j[i:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SqmCroK6u/j9TJ8s2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSHLqqAoM69EISvaKjPWOss2KzrTKvY/RExJCw6UuIDauVIrUpM1wMZpKRhr/jfWiTbUMdIxjuUygbNgYjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6ljqGBrEA)

Assumes that 1 chunk per line is acceptable output.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYy9CoQwEAZ7n2LLBL/C39ML@CRhi4gEN9xFEZt7@qgHguXMwKy/fV5ilZIfPu47To4EwQRycbLBGmHOvTqVFcM6@WW7OkkkVcOWqFCzBqnmCXdBgxYvdOjxRlmwNhnRuknc6f/U6QA) as a recursive lambda function

Comment: @ovs - Very nice and also different enough for you to post as your own answer if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, 71 bytes

```
,[>+>+<<-]>>>,[<[>.,<-]>>>++++[<++++++++>-]<.[-]<<<[<+>>+<-]<[->+<]>>>]
```

Dunno if this counts or not... input format:

```
<character whose ascii is n>AAAAAAAAAAAAA
For example, in the input:
 1234567890123492034
n is 32 since the ASCII value of space is 32
```

Takes the input and puts in a space every time `n` characters pass

Explanation (no commas because that would break the program):

```
, take n
[>+>+<<-] copy into next two cells (destroys original)
>>>, take first of A into next cell
[ while that input exists
<[>.,<-] if n is nonzero output take next of A subtract one from n
>>>++++[<++++++++>-]<.[-]< n is zero so put a space
<<[<+>>+<-] copy the old n into surrounding cells
<[->+<] move from first cell to second
>>>] take input, do again
```

Comment: Remove the spaces for 71 characters

Comment: lol, I thought I removed all of them but I didn't notice those, thanks!

Comment: Try reorganizing the cells such that the cells you use more are more accessible (for example, if the input cell (the one where you use `,` more) is used more it could be put an a cell which is easier to access than if it was placed in other cells) or use a bruteforcer. I am not skilled in golfing in BF so these suggestions may not be helpful.

Comment: So far I have `n n n A space` as my cell setup, if you can think of a better way...

Comment: Could `A space n n n ...` work (or `space A n n n...`)?

Comment: With the first one, it might make it worse (because I'd have to skip over two cells to get to n and back) and the third one might also increase it (because I'd have to jump forward at the beginning to take n first, and it would be the same but backwards otherwise)

Comment: Yes, correct. You may look at the question "Tips for golfing in brainf***" for more ways to golf

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 3 bytes

```
{/}
```

This is an anonymous block that takes an array of numbers and a number from the stack, and replaces them by an array of arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP0fbahgpGCsYKJgqmAWy2Xyv1q/9n9dwX8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ġ₎
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//8jCR019//9HRxvqGOkY65jomOqYxeqYxP6PAgA)

Comment: I read the statement, This came to mind immediately =). #builtinsFTW

Answer (score 4):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```
Enum.chunk_every
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p9mq6bx3zWvNFcvOaM0Lzs@tSy1qPK/vpEml6e/XmZecUFqcolCmp5GtKGOgpGOgrGOgomOgqmOglkskE@MImNiFJlo/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 1 byte

```
⪪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///RqlX//0crGRoZm5iamVtYKukomMQCAA) Charcoal's default I/O makes it difficult to demonstrate using anything except strings. If you want a full program that takes numeric lists and outputs formatted lists then this can be done as follows:

```
Ｅ⪪ＡＮ⪫ι,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjuCAns0TDM6@gtERDU0cBzPArzU1KLdLQBPK98jPzNDJ1FJR0lDQ1Na3//4@ONtRRMNJRMNZRMNFRMNVRMNNRMNdRsNBRsIwFCsX@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ａ      Input array
 ⪪       Split into chunks of
   Ｎ     Input number
Ｅ       Map over chunks
     ι  Current chunk
    ⪫   Joined with
      , Literal `,`
        Implicitly print each chunk on its own line
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 43 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>{int i=0;return a.GroupBy(_=>i++/b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5NS8QwEAbge3/FsKeEjrW7fhxME1BREfYoeFgWSUNqg7uJpK2yhPz2mg0riHNI4J0nM1HDmRrM/DhZ1Tw/2GmvvWx3ujF2FJgO/Bv@B0JAB3wmElvKRUgRGF4zr8fJW5DVk3fT592BvHFhyvK8pSzOrCi@pAcz6v0AHKz@3mzDEld4gZd4hdeR5b7qJ/txBB3JFFe0enG33ssDoWlG5zyQvDCZmqWrOb2p1tq@j32KypIWoYBUSWupeiC/q8HYE9@YLc3mWPfODm6nq1ef0NpYTRZZ3YQ6QljGBYLBPCD9Ic4/)

I think we should be able to just write `int i;` because 0 is the default of int. I let it to avoid the error: `error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'i'`.

Answer (score 4):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 15 bytes

```fs
Seq.chunkBySize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv0fbainZx5bY/c/OLVQLzmjNC/bqTI4sypVweh/jV1BUWZeSVqegpKqo9J/AA)

Well F# has a [builtin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.chunkbysize['t]-function-[fsharp])...

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
<\~-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/bWLqdP9rcqUmZ@QrGCoYKRgrmCiYKpgppCkYYxM0wSZoaGDwHwA)

Takes the array as left arg and chunk size as right arg.

Uses a dyadic hook and the [infix adverb](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/bslash#dyadic) with a negative argument, which does what we want by definition.

Note: The return type *must* be boxed because J only allows tables of equal sized items.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
òV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CmsP//ow11jHSMdUx0THXMYrmMFBQUuHQDAQ)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>106</s> 80 bytes

```
L->n->{for(int l=L.size(),i=0;i<l;)System.out.print(L.subList(i,(i+=n)<l?i:l));}
```

Prints the chunks without delimiter.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dU9LTsMwEN33FKOubMW1KJ8uSByEkJCQyqpLxMJNnWqC40SxUxSqbDkAR@QiwYnSggosbNnz3rxPJndylm1eukRLa@FRotlPAKyTDhPIPMprh5qntUkcFobfj4/oG1uiddGDcWqrqpj9tXRXGFvnqjqyYkhBdMtZbGbxPi0qgsaBFktu8U0RylCchRjpkK4a61TOi9rxsvIk4in1unckyAgGwtBI3@C1pjRsu3Dis5f1WvvsY4VdgRvIfS2ycl5g@/QMkvYVAf5pANr/QIBRrz8ot1Ulm8H3ZGa5tMN8zs7ZBbtkV2zhwwwOh2Yo5iFgJBb@DoLRHuBXOQym8Pn@AdNx3ytwWZa6IX0mymWSqNLTjvCpgjZkxNpJf9ruCw)

#### 106 bytes:

```java
L->n->{var r=new java.util.Stack();for(int l=L.size(),i=0;i<l;)r.add(L.subList(i,(i+=n)<l?i:l));return r;}
```

Actually returns a list of lists.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVC7TgMxEOzzFSsqW@dYhEcKfA6iQUIKVUpE4dwj2sTxney9oBCl5QP4RH7kcI5DBKTgwlrP7Kxndmk2ZrjMV21mTQjwaNDtBgCBDGEGy8jKhtDKsnEZYeXkfV@kP9wUA6UPjopF4SfiX1HfddzUqU8MiwdK0O10OHHDyW5jPHjtipcj@YxMtmJclZVn6AisnsqArwXjAvW5wtQq7qXJcxbxZn4Yz1AwTLTjqb3FG8u58gU13oFX@1YNYvy6mdsYv9/CpsIc1nEzbEYe3eLpGQw/bAnghG@w8QUaflu9895sOwN/sCBN6PCRuBCX4kpci3F01f3wnQv1SAGmehzvJOEdBzDbBirWsmpI1tEaWReTncHH2zucJaU0dW237GCG9zV@zd0P9u0n)

**Explanation:**

```java
L->n->{                       // Method with List and integer parameters and List return-type
  var r=new java.util.Stack();//  Create an empty List
  for(int l=L.size(),         //  Determine the size of the input-List
      i=0;i<l;)               //  Loop `i` in the range [0, size):
    r.add(                    //   Add to the result-List:
      L.subList(i,            //    A sublist of the input-list in the range from `i`
        Math.min(i+=n,l)));   //    to the minimum of: `i` + input-integer or the size
                              //    (and increase `i` by the input-integer at the same)
  return r;}                  //  Return the List of Lists of integers as result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45 bytes

```php
function f($a,$b){return array_chunk($a,$b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUEnVUkjSri1JLSovyFBKLihIr45MzSvOyoTLWtf8LijLzSuKLNNI0og11jHSMdUx0TGN1FIw0Na3/AwA)

Comment: Would just `array_chunk` be a valid answer?

Comment: @Arnauld I dont know. Never golfed in php before although I use it at work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either, but we can abuse the implicit conversion of undeclared variables to a string and do [something like that](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/sagosTI@OaM0L/u/NVdBUWZeSXyRhkqaRrShjpGOsY6JjmmsjoKRpqb1fwA).

Comment: (erratum: I meant undefined _constants_)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/4////0YY6RjrGsf@NAA)

While the printer makes it look like single-element splits are not wrapped into lists, [they actually are.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/44c4Z////jzbUMdIx1jHRMdUxi/1vCgA)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/4/@HlRyc93Dnj//9oQx0jHePY/0YA) night give a better output as to showing that single element arrays are still actually arrays.

Comment: Er, is the downvote because I didn’t add @Nick Kennedy’s link?

Comment: certainly not from me

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 10 bytes

```
{(0N,x)#y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWsPAT6dCU7my9n@aQrSCibWhgpGCsYKJgqmCmULsfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->n,a{[*a.each_slice(n)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ7E6WitRLzUxOSO@OCczOVUjTzO29n@BQlq0kU60oY6RjrGOiY6pjllsLBdI0BiboAma4H8A)

If we can return enumerators instead of arrays, then it becomes simply:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->n,a{a.each_slice n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ7E6US81MTkjvjgnMzlVIa/2f4FCWrSRTrShjpGOsY6JjqmOWWysXkl@fCIXSMYYp4wJNpn/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/), <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```lisp
(de f(n l)(if(>= n(length l))(list l)(cons(head n l)(f n(tail(- 0 n)l)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fco7DsJADIThnlNMOVsgAQl0cJc8dokly1mRbTj9xlBFihQXU/j7swyzypJr5RiRaNBASXw9YdRo7zL5J9Cb8qNhtoVT7Eb8y@RV6UR5xgUWvPSrzB@xogb3G3j1adDijofraavNobZ77b8x1BU)

Answer (score 3):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```
groupsof
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfpmCrEPM/vSi/tKA4P@1/tIaRjkK0oY6RjrGOiY6pjlmspo6ChjEWMRN0sViFGi07harMAjCdm1igolFQlJlXomCjpaenkKapUGOnALSzuDQ39T8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks AdmBorkBork*

```powershell
param($n,$a)$a|%{$b+=,$_
if($b.Count-ge$n){,$b;rv b}}
if($b){,$b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNCsIwEITveYqlrJLgKthWL1Io@CCSavyBWmtsVah59rpNRfSgOQxkZr4EpjzdjL3sTZ63uIUEmrbUVh8lFoRaoX4MGsxGCeFKHLYSs8nyVBfVeGewUA1htrBXyJzrQ@@41gmRSgF8SE4JIGUNKaKYZjRXxHd2FKUy7CTqJO5k1slcKfViw18s9SD1FH0g0W@E@o/oqx//63@9r@ABA2g8x@MAamtZzb0068pseDqeyIfWXOq8YmPIi2Lhmz4JXlEwNufgTQbCtU8)

Comment: You should be able to `rv b` (alias for `Remove-Variable`) instead of `$b=@()` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 6 bytes

```
òÀf,r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Cmww1pOkVc//8b6hjpGOuY6JjqmP03AQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f2c0 662c 720a                           ..f,r.
```

Explanation:

```
ò           " Until an error happens:
  f         "   (f)ind the...
 À          "     n'th...
   ,        "     ","
            "   (If there are less than n commas after the cursor, throw an error)
    r       "   Replace the char under the cursor with...
     <cr>   "     A newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 14 bytes

```
#(partition %)
```

builtins I guess

Comment: Hi, welcome. The function should take two arguments: the array to be partitioned and the length of the chunk. Also what happens if the last chunk isn't "full" when using partition?

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
import Data.Lists
chunksOf
```

Here's a more interesting version, with just a few more bytes (thanks to nimi for five bytes in each solution):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
n![]=[]
n!x=take n x:n!drop n x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08xOtY2OpYrT7HCtiQxO1UhT6HCKk8xpSi/AMT8n5uYmWdbUJSZV6JirKCooOQB1JWvUJKRWpSq9B8A)

Comment: I think you can

Comment: `n!x=take n x:n!drop n x`.  `Data.Lists` provides also `chunksOf`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>49</s> 36 bytes

```r
function(A,n)split(A,(seq(A)-1)%/%n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NRJ0@zuCAnswTI0ihOLdRw1NQ11FTVV83T/J@mYWhlpmOkyQVhGMMYJpr/AQ)

Thanks to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) for the golf.

Comment: How about this, for [36](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NRJ0@zuCAnswTI0ihOLdRw1NQ11FTVV83T/J@mYWhlpmOkyQVhGMMYJpr/AQ)

Comment: @KirillL. of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
#2~Partition~UpTo@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9moLiCxqCSzJDM/ry60ICTfQVntf0BRZl6JQ1q0kU61oY6RjrGOiY6pjlltLBdMwhiXhAmaxH8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```perl
$p=<>-1;s/(,.*?){$p}\K,/],[/g&&($_="[$_]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lwNbGTtfQulhfQ0dPy16zWqWgNsZbRz9WJ1o/XU1NQyXeVilaJT5WSfP//2hDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHYtYLqN/@QUlmfl5xf91cwoA)

Comment: instead of `&&(...)` you can do `;...` - this will save 3 bytes

Comment: also, you can embed expression in regexp using `@{[...]}`, so writing `@{[<>-1]}` instead of `$p` and calculating it will save another byte

Comment: hmm, I understand why you did this `&&` (not to put extra brackets when n is at least the length of a), but even the accepted answer does not do that

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 46 bytes

```
func[n l][until[print take/part l n empty? l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5VmpfA/rTQvOTpPISc2ujSvJDMnuqAoM69EoSQxO1W/ILGoRCFHIU8hNbegpNIeqCb2f5qCkUK0giGQNFYwUTBVMFOIVYBoUdLV1VXiSgOK45c3ISBviSH/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 38 bytes

Input is a series of numbers on stdin. The first number is `n`, and the rest of the numbers make up the array. Output consists of `n` comma-separated numbers per line, so each line is a chunk.

```
~Ilj~#l,'H!t<
vuj{ oN @j<c
>:&}>d2(nOl
```

## Example

```
In: 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
Out:
1,2
3,4
5,6

In: 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
Out:
1,2,3,4
5,6,
```

Note there will be a trailing comma if the last chunk is not the right size. Hopefully this is ok.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/7/OMyerTjlHR91DscSGq6w0q1oh30/BIcsmmcvOSq3WLsVII88/5/9/Ey5DBSMFYwUTBVMFMwVzBQsFSwVDAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 5 bytes

```
group
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQWFycn1yskF6UX1qQmZeuUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeikJ1alJeao2DNxVXNpQAE1UBoqGCkYKxgomCqYKZQC2TX4pAxxiljApSpVYjm@g@283@sQrSCnp6eQqxCcn5uQX5xKsRJuqmJyRn/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuociLCIiLCI0XG5bMSwyLDMsNCw1LDZdIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
proc &:each_slice
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvu/oCg/WUHNKjUxOSO@OCczOfV/gUJadLShjpGOsY6JjqmOWayOUaxeSX58IhemjDFOGROIzH8A)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 55 char, 110 bytes

```
{⍺≤1:,¨⍵⋄z←¯1↓v←,/(k←1+⌊⍺÷⍨≢⍵)⍺⍴⍵⋄0=r←⍺∣≢⍵:z⋄z,⊂r↑↑k⌷v}
```

this appear to return the right results... test:

```
  f←{⍺≤1:,¨⍵⋄z←¯1↓v←,/(k←1+⌊⍺÷⍨≢⍵)⍺⍴⍵⋄0=r←⍺∣≢⍵:z⋄z,⊂r↑↑k⌷v}
  o 1 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
┌6────────────────────────────┐
│┌1─┐ ┌1─┐ ┌1─┐ ┌1─┐ ┌1─┐ ┌1─┐│
││ 1│ │ 2│ │ 3│ │ 4│ │ 5│ │ 6││
│└~─┘ └~─┘ └~─┘ └~─┘ └~─┘ └~─┘2
└∊────────────────────────────┘
  2 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2  3 4  5 6 
  3 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3  4 5 6 
  4 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4  5 6 
  5 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5  6 
  6 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
  7 f 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,n:[x[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(x),n)]
```

Simple anonymous function implementation with a list comprehension. 
47 bytes if you don't count the `f=` assignment.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc1NDsIgGIThvaeYJcRZFFv8aeJJCAuMRUnq16bpAk@PGC9Qt/M@yczv9TlJW0q8juF1uwdkSu@yS33ai4/TgoQkWII8BtVwHERlTdG@zEuSVUXlGsIQB6IlOsISR@JEnImLr6vWu622@8Parbamb67dVGCqMJUY@/srHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 19 bytes

```
{a,n->a.chunked(n)}
```

o/ built-ins

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoJAFEX3fsXV1XugQmUtIoWWgT8xOEaD@hQdgxC/fRqDWnQXd3XP4Ta9bY24p2pxn6U6g0oz2ctNbBHDNyMpcJUXcreoWJJCpdVjlqbWJLw6z6BTRoixBPDZRIIcY610aaQmDsPU9t5E/Bvo/8E0tMZShIjTTg0LjP0yWD/UMBqxrdD2kXQszMHqsmCHPQ7IcMTpDQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 2 bytes

GS has a built-in. Unfortunately the implicit input got in the way.

```
~/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v07/f8J/I4VoQwUjBWMFEwVTBbNYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẇ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQSU4NyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTIlMEElNUIxJTJDMiUyQzMlMkM0JTJDNSUyQzYlNUQmZmxhZ3M9)

Yeah, another built-in :p

Polyglots with Vyxal apparently...