# Deal the cards to the players

Tags: code-golf, array

Tonight is card game night! You are the dealer and your task is to write a program to deal the cards to the players.

Given an array of cards and the number of players, you need to split the array of cards into a hand for each player.

[image: example for 4 players with a deck of 10 cards]

### Rules

Your program will receive an non-empty array `A` , as well as a non-zero positive integer `n`. The array should then be split into `n` hands. If the length of the string isn't divisible by `n` any leftover cards at the end should be distributed as evenly as possible.

- If `n==1`, you will need to return an array of array with `A` as it's only element
- If `n` is greater than the length of `A`, you will need to return every hand and an empty hand. if `n = 4` and `array A = [1,2,3]`, you should return `[[1],[2],[3]]` or  `[[1],[2],[3],[]]`. You are free to handle the empty hand with empty, undefined or null.
- The array can contain any type rather than a number.
- You should not change the order of the array while dealing. For example `if n = 2` and `A= [1,2,3]`, any result rather than `[[1,3],[2]]` will be invalid.

### Test Cases

```
n   A               Output

1   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
2   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
3   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
4   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,5],[2,6],[3],[4]]
7   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]] // or [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[]]
```

### Demo Program

```python
def deal(cards, n):
	i = 0
	players = [[] for _ in range(n)]
	for card in cards:
		players[i % n].append(card)
		i += 1
	return players

hands = deal([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2)

print(hands)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NCsIwEIXXmVPMRmhwENuqC6EnCUGCSW1ApmFaFz19bIIu38/3ZtK2TjP3Ofswog/u3Tyd@IWQ9R1UxAHPoNLbbUGWXRhjcZwFHxgZxfErNKwtqOIVsNh1YIf/mIl4QLYnl1JgX/f1nkY8DtiCkrB@hPFXBpgc@3KqPmNa6qinC13pZgk7DZAk8trUls75Cw)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you the shortest bytes of each language will be the winner.

Inspired from [Create chunks from array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/180970/67312) by [chau giang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84378/chau-giang)

Comment: *you will need to return every hands and an empty hand* contradicts the last test case's first result possibility.

Comment: In the future I'd recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to iron out problems and gauge community feedback before posting your question to main

Comment: @JoKing I fully agree. I didnt think I would have so much edit to do. It is like pushing to prod without deploying on beta first. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @aloisdg I can't parse your suggested alternate rule. If the idea is like people often deal to a circle, then all the players that end up with most cards are at the beginning, and players that are at the end may get no cards.

Comment: @Adám in the case of the empty hand? You are free to use any value suited in your language.

Comment: Can we use zero to indicate a missing card or empty hand e.g. n = 4   A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]      [[1,5],[2,6],[3,0],[4,0]]   or n = 4  A = [1,2,3]    [[1],[2],[3],[0]]

Comment: @Graham Yes zero is fine

Comment: What if the input array *contains* a `0`?

Comment: @Shaggy indeed it would be a problem. I dont know if there is a language without empty or null array where `[0]` would be the correct way to write it. I would like to avoid `[0]` but I dont want to block a lang where `[0]` is the only way to have an empty array.

Comment: @Shaggy with n=2 and A=["1","2","3","4","5","6"] the output should be [["1","3","5"],["2","4","6"]] and with n=4 and A=["1","2","3"] I could allow an output with [["1"],["2"],["3"],[0]] if the language cannot to `[]`, `null` etc.

Comment: Given that "*the card can be any kind of value (number, object, string, etc.)*" then `A=[0,1,2]` and `n=4` would give an output of `[[0],[1],[2],[0]]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>3</s> 1 byte

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Adnan*

```
ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M7//024og11jHSMdUx0THXMYgE)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h7udir6Sga6egZP//3M7/h9fr/I821DHSMdYx0THVMYsFAA)

**Explanation**

```
ι  # uninterleave
```

Does exactly what the challenge asks for

Comment: I think this should work as well: [`ι`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M7//024og11FIx0FIx1FEx0FEx1FMxiAQ)

Comment: @Adnan: Yeah thanks :) Only difference is the empty list for `n=7`, but that is an acceptable output format. I've totally missed that built-in :/

Comment: So there is a language with a built-in for this! :D

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 25 bytes

```r
function(A,n)split(A,1:n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NRJ0@zuCAnswTIMrTK0/yfnFiioaSLDEpSi0sUDJFFYvKUNLnSNAytzHQMNa1x6DDCocMIpw5jHDqMceowwaHDXJPrPwA)

`split`s `A` into groups defined by `1:n`, recycling `1:n` until it matches length with `A`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 24 bytes

```perl6
->\b{*.classify:{$++%b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX9cuJqlaSy85J7G4ODOt0qpaRVtbNam29n9afpGCoZ6eiUI1F2dxYqVCmoZKvKYGUMRMk6uWiwsiZKKpEW2oY6RjHKv5HwA)

Anonymous curried code block that takes a number and returns a Whatever lambda that takes a list and returns a list of lists. This takes the second option when given a number larger than the length of lists, e.g. `f(4)([1,2,3])` returns `[[1],[2],[3]]`

#### Explanation:

```perl6
->\b{                  }  # Anonymous code block that takes a number
     *                    # And returns a Whatever lambda
      .classify           # That groups by
               :{$++%b}   # The index modulo the number
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
(s=#;GatherBy[#2,#~Mod~s&])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PYVtnaHSRW5FQZrWyko1znm59SV6wWq6n2P6AoM69EwSE92lCn2lDHSMdYx0THVMesNpYLLmOEU8YYp4wJThlzNJn//wE)

Comment: Very cleverly done!

Comment: "The array can contain any type rather than a number."

Answer (score 6):

## Japt, 2 bytes

Takes the array as the first input.

```
óV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=81Y=&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2XQo0Ci1R)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 2 bytes

```
sZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7846v/h5UcnPdw54///aEMdIx1jHRMdUx2z2P8mAA)

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving 4 bytes

Comment: Does `sZ` not work?

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, somehow missed that. Do you want to post as separate answer or shall I edit mine?

Comment: No you're welcome to edit :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

#### Code:

```python
lambda x,n:[x[i::n]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fclLCoAgFAXQeau4w4Q30X4gtBJzYJQl1CvEga3eduCZnvdL58OqeMxYyuXudXPIxNpkE7Rm65@IgMCIjo@9ZWHLGwMn@NZIgiJ0hJ4wEEZLkKKptap3V@@@3pMoPw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
import Data.Lists
(transpose.).chunksOf
```

Note: `Data.Lists` is from the third-party library [lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists), which is not on Stackage and hence will not appear on Hoogle.

Comment: `Data.Lists` doesn't seem to exist. I would assume that you meant `Data.List`, but it doesn't contain `chunksOf`.

Comment: `chunksOf` only seems to appear with the signature `Int -> Text -> [Text]`.[1](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=chunksOf)

Comment: @JosephSible, it's in the `lists` package.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic, lots of things don't show up in Hoogle. It's in the `split` package and re-exported by the `lists` package. There are versions of `chunksOf` for lists, text, sequences, and probably other things.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>13</s>, <s>11</s>, <s>10</s>, 9 bytes

```
(|#\)</.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWqUYzRt9PVi/2typSZn5CsYKqQBsZGCsYKJgqmCGURQXR1CG@GTNMYnaYJP0hxV8j8A)

### how (previous explanation, fundamentally the same)

```
] </.~ (| #\)
  </.~          NB. box results of grouping
]               NB. the right arg by...
         |      NB. the remainders of dividing...
       [        NB. the left arg into...
           #\   NB. the length of each prefix of...
              ] NB. the right arg,
                NB. aka, the integers 1 thru
                NB. the length of the right arg
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＩＥθ✂ηιＬηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyE4JzM5VSNDRyFTR8EnNS@9JEMjQ1NHoVATCKz//4820Yk21DHSMdYx0THVMYuN/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `[n, A]` and outputs each value on its own line and each hand double-spaced from the previous. Explanation:

```
  θ         First input `n`
 Ｅ          Map over implicit range
    η       Second input `A`
   ✂        Sliced
     ι      Starting at current index
      Ｌη    Ending at length of `A`
        θ   Taking every `n`th element
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Comment: +1 for making the symbol of "slice" a scissors!

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
{a,n->(0..n-1).map{a.slice(it..a.size-1 step n)}}
```

The old, incorrect solution only worked for divisors of the array length. I'm certain this can be golfed down.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NCsIwEITvfYrR0wbaYP0DxRY8Cr5EqBEW07U0UdDSZ6@pigfnsMxhZj72cg2OZbgbh/NNqi3oyD7sDhLKFPEqZCX28kAxdCaVrKSZ1pLlStem6Yz2jitLHLSOnp82y@GDbSCq74e4iNqwkEKXIGrECAq01pyOLJbUZKLDNXJI/QKVaU/@P@Qbx4GmmH7AEfit9cm72LQswQmNT9B7IRWlkn7YJDnmWGCJFdYv)

Comment: [invalid](https://tio.run/##XY@xDoJAEER7vmKh2k24S1ALNXK9CX9gLC6A8eKxXOCwIfftCBgp3GKLycybzKv11vD01hYeA5dnwML0/nJlr1KYP4FQsEqbriCfRp2yUJhJySQb7UYnlJblc@BXXSHTaPzNieweQphmLjTaMBKMEcy3lDHk0NW6KgzXSHEsfTuzkTZDqbuq/zf1zhqPCSTfUuN/sRCtQdcZ9pZxmYIrIWWiKEz7KIMT7OAIhw8)

Comment: Doesn't work when `n` is not a divisor of the length of the list

Comment: I see, thanks. Fixing it now

Comment: I believe this is fixed @ASCII-only

Comment: [sadly this is longer](https://tio.run/##XY/NCoJAEMfvPsXkabZ0y@pQkULHwDeIDosaDOm46BaU7LPbah@H5jAw/D9@zLU2JXF/VyVcbpztAFNqzf7IJgnAbQFhAgd@QNx3KuAwwUhKFrJSutPuWkiJSrb0LEIt5h9BnfSMzJTD6Gyt7V0xVIoYBXQeuBloDDE0hcpT4gLFZCJN7XAofoZMNXn7b2p1SQZ98N8gMt@Y9cagbohNyTj8gmNDwEJ4tl95EWxhCRtYvwA)

Comment: rip. i got it down to 51 but still trying

Comment: looks like you can remove the extra pair ot parens

Comment: awesome, how did I miss that!

Comment: [close](https://tio.run/##XY/NCsIwEITvfYpREBJog/UXxBY8FnwHCTbCYrqWdhWl5NlrVfTgHOY0Mx9zvogn7m/W43Tl4wZqT61sC5Y8xuAaSY4dP5D1nY05ydXUGE5SbSpbd9acyItrCi7d3ZUdxYckpwlnGUkIoR8mUVlipdFFGPTiMDI0zpZ7Yqf0aGTkMoCU/gWOtinb/1BbexI1xvhDJvnWQvQu1g2xeFavF@q9ELPWUejXUYoZ5lhgidUT)

Comment: ah man, `filterIndexed` really kills you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90711/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-adam).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
#2[[i;;;;#]]~Table~{i,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9koOjrTGgiUY2PrQhKTclLrqjN1lGvV/gcUZeaVRFcrK9fq2qU5KCvHqjk4OChUc1Ub6gCRkY6xjomOqY5Zba0OV7URppAxppAJppA5Vo2OOk46zjouOq46brW1XLX/AQ)

Comment: O_o explanation pls

Comment: @ASCII-only `;; ;;` is just a slice, roughly equivalent to python's `: :`; this gets slices of every \$n\$th element for offsets 1...n

Comment: oh yeah, forgot it was `;;` not `;` lol. was looking at this going "wth is `i ; ; ; ; #`"

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
A=>n=>A.map((x,i)=>e[i%=n]=[...e[i]||[],x],e=[])&&e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoNADADQ01QSSAPaz0Yy4DlCFoONZYqdkVrEhXef9q3eK25xHT9p@Z5zeXidpA4SsoSB33EB2CmhBNd0kmyizPy/HYca7UYuatg0Xvux5LXMznN5wgTaUkcXutKN7obQIfb1Bw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
A=>n=>g=(i=n)=>i?[...g(--i),A.filter(_=>i--%n==0)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclRCsIwDADQ0wgJJEGd@uFIZecoRcZsS6Wksg2vX32/7z1/521Zy2dna6/Yk/ZJnanLCkUN1ZWHF5EMzAVpklTqHld4/oP5YKpHDHcf@rg021qNUluGBP5EZxroQle6BYQBAXHsPw)

Answer (score 2):

## TSQL, 44 bytes

```
-- @       : table containing the input 
-- column c: value of the card, 
-- column a: position on the card in the deck
-- @n      : number of players

DECLARE @ table(a int identity(0,1), c varchar(9))
DECLARE @n int = 4

INSERT @ values('1a'),('2c'),('3e'),('4g'),('5i'),('6k')

SELECT string_agg(c,',')FROM @ GROUP BY a%@n
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1000657/deal-the-cards-to-the-players)**

Comment: Every time I'm on this website I see something new and go "Wow that's impressive, but why?"

Comment: @MindSwipe I have answered a lot of questions on StackOverflow, but many of those questions are the same or almost the same - also it feels like I am working for free. The code-golf questions are different every time and I enjoy it more because I get to use methods I rarely otherwise encounter.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 81 bytes

```
def s a,n;a.each_with_index.inject(([[]]*n).map(&:dup)){|b,(c,d)|b[d%n]<<c;b};end
```

[Try It Online](https://repl.it/repls/HoneydewOilyPlots)

Comment: Could you possibly add a link to an online testing environment for ease of verification?

Comment: @JonathanFrech There you go.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There's a lot of optimizations you can do for length; for example, `each_with_index` is pretty expensive compared to an incrementing counter, `map{[]}` basically does the same thing as your `map(&:dup)` trick, anonymous Proc, etc. that can reduce your code down to 59 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNCsMgFEbReVbhpKD0i/TF/pLYjYgDmwZqoBJMOyjGtVtwejk3fh@/surS3h1C8rql3kkf5mn8cE5SBiHfbknGZpG2iGmLhvu9JrELdhimPuZcRhefK9PMEDooHHHCGRdccQMdQATqQMo2LxeqU83CVlMvsBpt@QM "Ruby – Try It Online") Also check out [the Ruby tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/363/52194)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN 26 or 31 bytes

If individual hands can be represented as columns of a 2D matrix then 26 bytes if an array of arrays then add 5 bytes.

```
(l,n)⍴((l←⌈(⍴a)÷n)×n←⎕)↑a←⎕
```

[Try it online! ourtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r5OjkaT7q3aKhkQMUfNTToQHkJGoe3p6neXh6Hkiob6rmo7aJiRDmf6Cm/2lchgpGCsYKJgqmCmZcJgA)

or

```
⊂[1](l,n)⍴((l←⌈(⍴a)÷n)×n←⎕)↑a←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6mqKNozVyNHJ03zUu0VDIwco9ainQwPISdQ8vD1P8/D0PJBQ31TNR20TEyHM/0Ct/9O4DBWMFIwVTBRMFcy4TAA)

Explanation:

a←⎕ prompt for array of cards

((l←⌈(⍴a)÷n)×n←⎕)↑ prompt for integer, pad a with zeros to given even hands

(l,n)⍴ create 2D matrix with each column representing each hand

⊂[1] if required convert to nested vector - APL array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 9 bytes

```
\ô_í\%q╞;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/m8Jb4w2tjVAsfTZ1n/f9/tKGOkY6xjomOqY5ZrIIhFyrfCI1vjMY3QeObovHN0fiGqAbomOtY6FjqGBroGBrqGBoB9f8HAA)

### Explanation

```
\           swap top elements (pops both input onto stack)
 ô          start block of length 6
  _         duplicate TOS (will duplicate the list)
   í        get total number of iterations of for loop (the other input)
    \       swap top elements
     %      modulo (picks every n:th item of the list
      q     print without newline
       ╞    discard from left of string/array (makes the next player pick cards starting with the next in the deck)
        ;   discard TOS (removes some junk in the end)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>85</del> <del>83</del> 82 bytes

```php
function($a,$n){while($x<$n)$c[]=array_column(array_chunk($a,$n),+$x++);return$c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BS8NAEIXv@RVDWciGzMGmTaWkUaQKPQi26C2GsKxbN1p3w2aDldLfHndDjrk85n0z83iNbPrNfSMbEMZoUxnRaGNr9UlvoiwgIu@PneK21ooShkRFl19ZnwQl540zhBdlzoxhfxXXp@5H0dHITn2PDxiTcxxHmRG2M4rw7NpnQUCsaG0LORQBwBzyOyjmmOACl5jiqkRHk0m6mKTLSXo7SdOBhuttiOHh0Uny6mS5c7Ly9sHbtZ/ePEu3oXsrXeejNoJxSWEsz1ogyocRBhFcXLTgUjuGMHu3M4SvVqtKKK4/BB2OphfDEn1W5E/2u3319PKcBdf@Hw)

This will not be the shortest entry, but I thought it'd be fun to try and do it using PHP array function built-ins.  Result: long.

***Output***

```php
1   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
2   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
3   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
4   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1,5],[2,6],[3],[4]]
7   [1,2,3,4,5,6]   [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[]]
5   ["9C","QD","2S","4H","6D","AS","9D","TH","5C"]  [["9C","AS"],["QD","9D"],["2S","TH"],["4H","5C"],["6D"]]
```

Comment: Just FYI, instead of `print_flat` you can just do `json_encode`  [sandbox](https://tio.run/##bY/LasMwEEX3/orBDNgiouThpATFLSUtZFFoSrtzjRGqUqdNJCPb4BLy7c4oZOnNRfcMcxhVZdWvHquyAu2cdYXTlXXN3vzEYyYC1Gm/a41q9tbEKDkadtpZF2OXjgV2KzSCocryVDon/wtlD@3RxLdStubvtsSxG42YcLppnUElzr0IAmx03dSQQhYATCB9gGzCp3zGEz7ni5wTnQ7S2SBNBun9IJ1fabRcRzx6f6aYflAkG4qFr0@@Lv3r07P5OqK1nG6mz2upyhhux8sa0HgZSmBwIrVWpSXGIfxqQsoshDvYH6uD/dYxuThKRiTMr@Pf2ppCG@WHqEkruRcyxrebbfHy9iqCc38B)  - dosn't really change the answer any, just thought I would mention it, cheers!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix well, of course! (facepalm) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 90 bytes

```java
A->n->{var o="";for(int h=0,i;h<n;o+="\n")for(i=h++;i<A.length;i+=n)o+=" "+A[i];return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZE9b8IwEIb3/IqTp6Q2VvloK9U4UpZKHToxUgYDgRw1duQ4SAjlt6dJsBBDbrIfv6d7bJ/URU1O@78Wz6V1Hk7dntceNT/UZufRGv4iorLeatzBTquqgh@FBm4RdFV55Tv@FaJLNH69Yd/GP8jKOzTHNIV9rjTINpukZpLeLsqBlYSIg3Vx1wWFfGUoiqURlkrya0gynMiCUoHLjOvcHH0hkEqT9AkgNFvjRrjc186AFU0rosEpuAa1i8U9nDvj@G6y3oByxyoJF@hrkIYMJNxgymDGYM5gweCNwTs04pEru34fZwymyQicjcH5GFyMwY8Am@j5YQf7eyZYsl4X8Nl/da18fua29nyIahMTIwlFSj6BPA0bCfa/wlVZ6mucJWGBycOlaf8B)

Thanks [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) for the lambda and better incrementing while iterating.

Comment: And here, [I golfed it down to 90 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZE9b8IwEIb3/IqTp6Q2VvloK9U4UpZKHToxUgYDgRw1duQ4SAjlt6dJsBBDbrIfv6d7bJ/URU1O@78Wz6V1Hk7dntceNT/UZufRGv4iorLeatzBTquqgh@FBm4RdFV55Tv@FaJLNH69Yd/GP8jKOzTHNIV9rjTINpukZpLeLsqBlYSIg3Vx1wWFfGUoiqURlkrya0gynMiCUoHLjOvcHH0hkEqT9AkgNFvjRrjc186AFU0rosEpuAa1i8U9nDvj@G6y3oByxyoJF@hrkIYMJNxgymDGYM5gweCNwTs04pEru34fZwymyQicjcH5GFyMwY8Am@j5YQf7eyZYsl4X8Nl/da18fua29nyIahMTIwlFSj6BPA0bCfa/wlVZ6mucJWGBycOlaf8B).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks! Somewhat new to this and was working on the lambda bit but struggling.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-la`, <s>66</s> 56 bytes

```perl
$,=<>;map{push@$_,shift@F}1..$,while@F;say"@$_"for 1..$,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx9bGzjo3saC6oLQ4w0ElXqc4IzOtxMGt1lBPT0WnPCMzJ9XBzbo4sVIJKKmUll@kAJb4/99QwUjBWMFEwVTBjMvQ4F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ujmJAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 43 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>{int i=0;return a.GroupBy(_=>i++%b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7fS8MwEAfw9/4Vx0BI6Fm6@ePBNAEVFWGPgg9jSBpSG9wSSVtlhPztNQsTxHtI4Huf3EUN52ow8@NkVfP8YKe99rLd6cbYUWA68G/4HwgBHfCZSGwpFyFFYHjNvB4nb0FWT95Nn3cH8saFKcuzlrI4s6L4kh7MqPcDcLD6e7MNS1zhBV7iFV5Hlvuqn@zHEXQkU1zR6sXdei8PhKYZnfNA8sJkapau5vSmWmv7PvYpKktahAJSJa2l6oH8rgZjT3xjtjSbY907O7idrl59QmtjNVlkdRPqCGEZFwgG84D0hzj/AA)

Comment: @JoKing `[1,2,3], 4` should output `[[1],[2],[3]]`. You are dealing 3 cards to 4 players. I will update the main question.

Comment: It's generally discouraged to post solutions to your own challenges immediately.

Comment: @Shaggy ok I will take it into account for the next time. It is fine on so and rpg but I guess the competitive aspect of codegolf made it a bit unfair to self post directly. Make sense.

Comment: @Joe king you are right! I made a typo :/

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 5 bytes

The compiler flag `-Df=` (req. leading space) fulfills specification. `f(n_cards,n_hands,card_ptr)` evaluates to a pointer to a list of hands.

## Explanation

In C, it is common practice to implement lists of lists as a single interleaved array, when the number of lists remains constant but all lists can be extended. For example, in this case of dealing cards, it is more common for more cards to get added to each hand than more hands to be added, so it would be reasonable to implement a list of hands as an interleaved list. Coincidentally, the "deck" is such a list, and thus we return the parameter unmodified.

This challenge probably should've been sandboxed.

Comment: I think we all agree for the sandbox